# How easy is it to keep two LVM partitions in sync

Tags: backup, lvm

I've got an Ubuntu 14 VM (holding backups) with two very large disks. One disk (the primary) is locally in the data center. The other is on media physically separate (another building). My hope is to easily take a snapshot of the primary file system and then update the secondary with that data.

If I were using ZFS, this would be quite easy. I'm not sure if it is nearly so easy with LVM/ext4 though.

I'm familiar with how to take a snapshot of the file system with LVM. (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html). However, everything I find on google (including this link) seems to suggest mounting the snapshot and then backing up the file contents. I'd prefer to duplicate the file system itself.

The question [Sync LVM snapshots to backup server](https://serverfault.com/questions/27397/sync-lvm-snapshots-to-backup-server) is very similar. Though in my case, I'd like to duplicate to a second LVM partition rather than to a file on a remote server.

Comment: Would [drbd](https://www.drbd.org/en/) help out at all? This is a tool for keeping a block device in sync with a remote copy. It's more of an ha tool than a backup tool.

Comment: That question, and its answers, apply to periodic syncs to a remote device, not just to a file.